# ActionBarDrawerToggle customization

Tags: android, android-appcompat, actionbardrawertoggle

How to change icon for ActionBarDrawerToggle in android using AppCompat V7? Also, how can we specify params and padding etc for ActionBarDrawerToggle icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
     toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_good);
```

Add these lines in your onCreate() method , also add

> toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_good);

add this line after

> toggle.syncstate();

and also in toggle listeners.
Android will pick default icon every time you open or close the drawer, so its important to put this line in toggle listeners also.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the toggle functionality you can set a custom toggle listener

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(<Activity>, <DrawerLayout>, <Toolbar>, <String open>, <String close>){//override functionality};
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
```

I don't think you can manually set the padding as this is a system button but you can manually set your own icon with its own padding

```
drawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_drawable));
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to disable drawer indicator

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

and then set `ToolBar's` navigation button :

```
 mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.navIcon);
```

However, but in that case you will have to set Navigation click listner on toolbar and open NavigationDrawer manualy.